# Cannot install angular fancy grid via npm

Tags: angular, npm

I am following the instructions to install angular fancy grid using npm but there is an error.

I have tried this

```
npm install --save fancygrid fancy-grid-angular
```

and errors appear

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from fancy-grid-angular@0.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/fancy-grid-angular
npm ERR!   fancy-grid-angular@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-17T04_37_31_724Z-debug-0.log
```

Documentation: [fancy grid](https://fancygrid.com/docs/getting-started/angular)

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: @s_erfani i am using version 15

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have dependency conflict. probably your dependency is compatible with lower version of angular. like it said it is using `@angular/common@"^6.0.0` but yours is using `@angular/common@"^15.2.0"` you can try downgrading but it's better to do as it said and try `--legacy-peer-deps`:

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: It seems this library doesn't support new version of angular, i think i will try with other libraries, by the way thank you for your help

Comment: yeah it seems that its deprecated. your welcome @HoangSon